# Is Thomas Wedgwood's picture actually the first photograph?

Tags: photography

I understand that a google search usually answers such questions, but I don't seem to find a definitive answer to this question. The University of Texas claims that [the earliest known surviving photograph made in a camera](http://www.hrc.utexas.edu/exhibitions/permanent/firstphotograph/), was taken by Joseph Nicéphore Niépce in 1826 or 1827, even though I can find a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Wedgwood_(photographer)) about Wedgwood with his portrait on it. Wedgewood died in 1805 before the Utexas photo was taken.

Answer (score 4):

Thomas Wedgwood's portrait is not a photograph. If you click on the picture and look at the attribution of Wedgwood's portrait on the Wikipedia page, it states:

> From a chalk drawing belonging to Miss Wedgwood, of Leith Hill Place.
>   Artist unknown.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73850/discussion-on-answer-by-sempaiscuba-is-thomas-wedgwoods-picture-actually-the-fi).

Answer (score 2):

If you read the Wikpedia article, it states that the best Wedgwood did was to make shadow image photograms which are done by placing an object on photosensitive paper and exposing it to light such as the leaf illustration included in the article.  He did not make any images that today would be called photographs.